# convert tuple keys of dict into a new dict

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a `dict` like this:

```
{
    ('America', 25, 'm', 'IT'): 10000,
    ('America', 22, 'm', 'IT'): 8999,
    ('Japan',   24, 'f', 'IT'): 9999,
    ('Japan',   23, 'f', 'IT'): 9000
}
```

Now, I want to get all result with key `('America', 'm', 'IT')`, in this example. In the above, that would be:

```
{25: 10000, 22: 8999}
```

My current solution is below:

```
res = dict()
for key, cnt in stats.items():
    country, age, sex, job = key
    try:
        res[(country, sex, job)][age] = cnt
    except KeyError as e:
        res[(country, sex, job)] = {}
        res[(country, sex, job)][age] = cnt

print res['America', 'm', 'IT']
```

Do I have better ways to do is? since this code does not seem that simple.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: @StefanPochmann an easier way to do this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a dict comprehension to do this:

```
>>> data = {
...     ('America', 25, 'm', 'IT'): 10000,
...     ('America', 22, 'm', 'IT'): 8999,
...     ('Japan',   24, 'f', 'IT'): 9999,
...     ('Japan',   23, 'f', 'IT'): 9000
... }
>>> {x: value for (w, x, y, z), value in data.items() if w == "America" and y == "m" and z == "IT"}
{25: 10000, 22: 8999}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since I like `namedtuples`, here would be an alternative suggestion:

Store your dictionary as a list or set of `namedtuples`, e.g.,

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Entry = namedtuple('entry', ('country', 'age', 'sex', 'job', 'count'))
```

To convert your existing dictionary `dt`:

```
>>> nt = [Entry(*list(k) + [dt[k]]) for k in dt]
```

Now, you could fetch the desired entries in a quite readable way, e.g.,

```
>>> results = [i for i in nt if (i.country=='America' and i.sex=='m' and i.job=='IT')]
```

Or, for example, to get the `count`s:

```
>>> [i.count for i in nt if (i.country=='America' and i.sex=='m' and i.job=='IT')]
[8999, 10000]
```

### Edit: Performance

Was not sure if you were looking after performance since you mentioned "easier way to do it".
You are right, the pure "comprehension is faster:

```
dt = {
    ('America', 25, 'm', 'IT'): 10000,
    ('America', 22, 'm', 'IT'): 8999,
    ('Japan',   24, 'f', 'IT'): 9999,
    ('Japan',   23, 'f', 'IT'): 9000
}

nt = [Entry(*list(k) + [dt[k]]) for k in dt]

%timeit {i.age:i.count for i in nt if (i.country=='America' and i.sex=='m' and i.job=='IT')}

100000 loops, best of 3: 3.62 µs per loop

%timeit {x: value for (w, x, y, z), value in dt.items() if w == "America" and y == "m" and z == "IT"}

100000 loops, best of 3: 2.42 µs per loop
```

But if you have a larger dataset and querying it over and over again I would also think about Pandas or SQLite.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([list(x[0]) + [x[1]] for x in dt.items()])
df.columns = ['country', 'age', 'sex', 'job', 'count']
df
```

[image]

```
df.loc[(df.country=='America') & (df.sex=='m') & (df.job=='IT')]
```

[image]

Comment: but I do not think namedtuple have as good performance as dict, such as I want to get frequently with (country, sex, job), you always need to traversal the list, hash may perform better

Comment: why does Entry have the argument *list(k) +[dt[k]]?  what is happening here.  It looks like Entry receives a list of keys and a list of value but what throws me is the + sign between the two lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your entire try/except with this:

```
res.setdefault((country, sex, job), {})[age] = cnt
```

Or you could make `res` a `defaultdict(dict)` and then it becomes:

```
res[country, sex, job][age] = cnt
```